# What are the Stephen King connections in The Dark Tower series?

Tags: intertextuality, stephen-king, the-dark-tower-king

There's plenty of connections to King's other works in The Dark Tower. Most notably Salem's Lot.

What other connections are there, no matter how big or small?

Comment: As a general point, King loves cross-references in all his books. It helps that most of them are set in one or two small Maine towns.

Comment: I regret to say that I think this question is too broad.  The Dark Tower series connects to most of King's books, as well as several of his movies and television shows - often in incredibly minor ways (such as a "Nozz-A-La" soda machine in Kingdom Hospital).

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131740/dark-tower-references-in-other-works-of-stephen-king-or-vice-versa/131767#131767 why vote to close as to broad, we have a similar question on the topic on SFF, the Answer appears to be simply a short list nothing extensive.

Comment: The "no matter how big or small" language makes me uncomfortable; I'd think that an exhaustive list would be impossible to provide in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of them. By the end of *The Dark Tower*, it is revealed that the story takes place

> in a vast multiverse, in which every book by Stephen King -- and possibly every story ever told -- is a separate universe linked together at the Dark Tower. So, even Stephen King stories not explicitly linked still take place in the same multiverse, and may even have been written by the Stephen King we meet in the series.

If you're looking for a list of every explicit reference, [Wikipedia had a good list going that you can edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King_works_related_to_The_Dark_Tower_series), but this has been deleted. I'm leaving that link in just in case someone recreates that page, but otherwise you can read the list [on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20161116023558/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King_works_related_to_The_Dark_Tower_series).

Comment: The wikipedia page seems to have been removed, shorter overview [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_(series)#Connections_to_King.27s_other_works)

Comment: Thanks, @Raidri! I've added an archive.org link to the page I linked to.

Comment: Could you include some of the info from that link in the answer itself? I don't know whether archive.org links ever go dead like the original link did, but in any case it's nice to have the info on *this* site rather than linked elsewhere.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think my answer completely answers the original question: every Stephen King story ever written or to be written is by definition a part of the "Dark Tower" universe. But I think listing individual instances of explicit overlap could and should be a separate answer!